# IBM Liberty Profile Context Root Not Found

Tags: spring, websphere-liberty, contextroot

I've deployed a spring application to IBM Liberty Profile. Both of the server and the application starts without problem, but when I would like to reach the application the browser says "Context Root Not Found"

I've configured the application in several ways in the server.xml

```
<application location="d:/Work/Installed Liberty Applications/OFRAdminEAR/OFRAdmin.ear" 
                 name="OFRAdmin" 
                 security-role="false"
                 id="OFRAdmin"
                 type="ear">
    <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec,ibm-api,api" privateLibraryRef="WebspherePlugins, OFRAdminsSharedLibrary"/>
    </application>

    <enterpriseApplication location="d:/Work/Installed Liberty Applications/OFRAdminEAR/OFRAdmin.ear"
                   id="OFRAdmin"
                   name="OFRAdmin"
                   security-role="false"
                   type="ear">
    <classloader privateLibraryRef="WebspherePlugins, OFRAdminsSharedLibrary" />
    </enterpriseApplication>

    <webApplication location="d:/Work/Installed Liberty Applications/OFRAdminEAR/OFRAdmin.ear"
                id="OFRAdmin"
                name="OFRAdmin"
                security-role="false"
                type="war">
    <classloader privateLibraryRef="WebspherePlugins, OFRAdminsSharedLibrary" />
    </webApplication>
```

The application packed into an ear file, which contains a WAR file and META-INF folder with the application.xml. The application.xml looks like this.

```
    <application-name>OFRAdmin</application-name>
    <display-name>OFRAdmin</display-name>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>OFRAdmin.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>OFRAdmin</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

What I missed? Where should I set the context root of the application? Can anybody help me?

Comment: can you check the messages.log file (in the logs/ folder of your server directory)?  It should indicate have some helpful error messages indicating if the app was even found, and if it was, what issues occurred attempting to start the app.  If the app started successfully, it will log the context root of the application

Comment: Should the context-root begin with a / there?