# WLP:Context root not found

Tags: jsp, websphere-liberty, servlet-3.0

When I go to visit my application locally http://localhost:9080/, I get the "Welcome to the WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile" error.

The Liberty profile version as below

Product name: WebSphere Application Server

Product version: 20.0.0.4

Product edition: BASE

**Excepted**
when user visit domain or locally its should redirect to login page as http://localhost:9080/tis

**logs**

```
[INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: Shop.
[INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module Technical Information Shop has been bound to default_host.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://wvdweu002-203.xx.net:9080/tis/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application TisEar started in 49.679 seconds.
[INFO    ] SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/tis
[INFO    ] SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[INFO    ] SRVE0242I: [TisEar] [/tis] [action]: Initialization successful.
```

**Application configuration**
Application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <display-name>TisEar</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>TisWeb-MASP_JPA.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/tis</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>TisDomain-MASP_JPA.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>
```

**Ear pom.xml**

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
          <version>6</version>
          <earSourceDirectory>${basedir}/EarContent</earSourceDirectory>
          <earSourceIncludes>**/*.policy,**/*.xmi</earSourceIncludes>
          <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars> 
           <modules>
             <webModule>
               <groupId>com.xx.tis</groupId>
               <artifactId>TisWeb</artifactId>
               <contextRoot>/tis</contextRoot>
             </webModule>
            </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

**server.xml**

**not working:** any of below

```
    <enterpriseApplication id="TisEar" location="TisEar-MASP_JPA.ear" name="TisEar"> 
     <web-ext context-root="/tis" moduleName="TisWeb-MASP_JPA"/>  
    </enterpriseApplication> 
    
    <webApplication id="TisWeb" location="TisWeb-MASP_JPA.war" name="TisWeb">
    <web-ext context-root="/tis"></web-ext>
    </webApplication>

   <application context-root="/tis" type="war" id="tis"   location="TisWeb-MASP_JPA.war" name="tis"/>
```

**Below of links not helpfull to resolve above issue**

[WLP :: Change default context root on http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873827/wlp-change-default-context-root-on-http)

[IBM Liberty Profile Context Root Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157787/ibm-liberty-profile-context-root-not-found)

[WebSphere Liberty Profile: Context Root Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135222/websphere-liberty-profile-context-root-not-found)

Comment: Your context-root is `/tis` so your application is available at `http://localhost:9080/tis` NOT `http://localhost:9080/`. There is no automatic redirection from `/` to anything. Why are you expecting that? If you want your app to be available at root context you should define `application context-root="/"` instead of `/tis`

Comment: If you want automatic redirect you need to add `httpDispatcher` element in `server.xml` as was discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26874158/3701228

Comment: if i use httpDispatcher 
   
 working but for fraction of second showing as notFound page before redirecting to /tis login page
     <httpDispatcher appOrContextRootMissingMessage="&lt;script&gt;document.location.href=&quot;/tis/&quot;;&lt;/script&gt;" enableWelcomePage="false"/>

how to avoid notfound page?

Comment: You can either conf your app on `/` context  not `/tis` or use http server (like apache or IHS) to rewrite requests.